# JSON not indexing correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, discord.js

I have this JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "type": "GUILD_TEXT",
    "deleted": false,
    "guild": "898666651547996200",
    "guildId": "898666651547996200",
    "parentId": "903388176100495390",
    "permissionOverwrites": [
      "900991433576689675",
      "917426278003523604",
      "898666651547996200",
      "898825198709641246"
    ],
    "messages": [
      "928781911982219307"
    ],
    "threads": [],
    "nsfw": false,
    "id": "903388255528042566",
    "name": "updates",
    "rawPosition": 41,
    "topic": null,
    "lastMessageId": "928781911982219307",
    "rateLimitPerUser": 0,
    "createdTimestamp": 1635454944260
  }
]
```

(call = the json)

Shouldn't this be returning `"updates"`: `call[0]["name"]`

Via JS, it is returning `undefined`.

`call[0]` is returning as `{`

I've tried it on various other languages and it has been working as intended... just not in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work:

```js
const call = [{
  "type": "GUILD_TEXT",
  "deleted": false,
  "guild": "898666651547996200",
  "guildId": "898666651547996200",
  "parentId": "903388176100495390",
  "permissionOverwrites": [
    "900991433576689675",
    "917426278003523604",
    "898666651547996200",
    "898825198709641246"
  ],
  "messages": [
    "928781911982219307"
  ],
  "threads": [],
  "nsfw": false,
  "id": "903388255528042566",
  "name": "updates",
  "rawPosition": 41,
  "topic": null,
  "lastMessageId": "928781911982219307",
  "rateLimitPerUser": 0,
  "createdTimestamp": 1635454944260
}]

console.log(call[0]["name"]) // updates

const callString = JSON.stringify(call)
console.log(JSON.parse(callString)[0]["name"]) // updates
```

Comment: If I am using JSON.stringify on a collection to get the JSON, should that still be working?

Comment: If you have a JSON (A STRING, NOT AN OBJECT), you must do JSON.parse(theStringContainingTheJson)

Comment: @Inobservatus Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
var name= call[0].name;
```

and

```
var name= call[0]["name"];
```

evertything is working properly returning "updates".